# I have get an error when using a function from a class

Tags: c#

I have created a Hangman game. But all the code was in the GUI. I have been reading a lot of programming books and I want to use functions and really program object orientated instead of putting everything in the GUI. So I tried creating a function that generates a random word but it doesn't work. It throws an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

```
class GetSecretWord
{
    public static string GetWord()
    {
        string unsortedwords = "master,bother,bucket,legend,method";
        List<string> sortedwords = unsortedwords.Split(',').ToList();

        int index = new Random().Next(sortedwords.Count);
        string secretWord = sortedwords[index];

        return GetWord();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, in my Form code:

```
 private void btn_Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string theSecretWord = GetSecretWord.GetWord();
        MessageBox.Show(theSecretWord);
    }
```

I use a messagebox to test if it works but it doesn't...

Comment: You should return secretWord, but instead of that you are calling the same method again and again...

Comment: If you put your word list in a Stack, you could randomize the words and Pop one at a time and not have to worry about repeats.  You should also use one Random instance for the entire life of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your return to return `secretWord`

```
 public static string GetWord()
 {
    string unsortedwords = "master,bother,bucket,legend,method";
    List<string> sortedwords = unsortedwords.Split(',').ToList();

    int index = new Random().Next(sortedwords.Count);
    string secretWord = sortedwords[index];

    return secretWord;
}
```

Right now you are recursively calling the function which is causing the stack overflow exception.

Comment: When I do that there is an error: Method name expected | I tried this before and tried to return the secretWord but when it gave that error it really caught me off guard.